# Storage path outside root directory

Tags: laravel, caching, filesystems, storage

I am trying to store the file cache data outside my Laravel project. I have added the below snippet in my cache config file.

```
      'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('Users/path/to'),
        ],
```

However, the folder hierarchy passed within `storage_path` is getting appended and cached data is stored within root directory. 
Any suggestion on how do I provide a path so that I can store it outside the laravel project.

Comment: Try using class Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [storage_path](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-storage-path) function prepends the path given with the path to your app's storage directory, so will always return a directory inside the storage path. If you want to specify a path outside your app, just remove the function:

```
'file' => [
    'driver' => 'file',
    'path' => 'Users/path/to',
],
```

Depending on how you have your webserver configured, you may run into problems with permission errors. I would consider using a symbolic link inside the storage path, rather than directly linking to a path outside.